# How many subrectangle exists on a m x n grid

Tags: algorithm

Given a `m x n` grid, how many unique sub-rectangles exist on such a grid?

For example,

`1 x 1` grid has 1 sub-rectangle.

`1 x 2` grid has 3 sub-rectangles.

I am looking for a general formula that can be used to directly compute the number existing sub-rectangle.

Comment: How many triangles of size a x b are there on an m x n grid? Now sum that up for all a and b.

Comment: I am looking for a single formula.

Comment: And I am trying to help you find it.

Comment: Dynamic programming would be perfect for this.

Comment: @VivinPaliath No, there is a simple formula

Comment: Given a `m x n` grid and a anchor point `i, j`, the total number of sub-rectangles that use the anchor point as top-left corner is `(m-i+1)*(n-j+1)`.

Comment: Well, I had an answer typed out for you, but I like @ChrisTaylor's idea of leading you to it.  So, questions to help you:  How did you know a 1x2 has 3 sub-rects?  How many sub-rects would be in a 1x5?  If you understand one dimension, finding the combinations for 2 is easy.

Comment: @q0987 Right! So you get the answer by summing that over all i=1...m and j=1...n. It will help to expand the brackets some. Do you know the formula for the sum of whole numbers between 1 and N?

Comment: I think Thomash has given me the perfect solution as follows. Thank you all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is `m(m+1)n(n+1)/4`.

a rectangle is defined by its two projections on the x-axis and on the y-axis.

projection on x-axis : number of pairs (a,b) such that 1 <= a <= b <= m = m(m+1)/2

idem for y-axis

Comment: Dude, Cooooool.

Answer (score 16):

Same answer as @Thomash provided, but with a bit more explanation, posting for posterity:

If you can figure this out in one dimension, it's easy to move it into two dimensions.

Let's look at a 1x5:

```
 5 1x1 squares
+4 1x2 squares
+3 1x3 squares
+2 1x4 squares
+1 1x5 squares = 15 squares.
```

The formula for this is simple: `sum = n(1 + n)/ 2`.  In the case of 5, you want 5(1+5)/2 = 15.

So, to get your answer, just do this for n and m, and multiply them:

```
sumN = n(1+n)/2
sumM = m(1+m)/2
totalRectangles = nm(1+n)(1+m)/4
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a nice solution, 
Lets look at the table borders of the grid. 
And to create a rectangle we need four points on the borders. 
2 points horizontal and 2 vertical

for example (n = 4, , m = 5) 
Note that the choice is for N + 1 and M + 1
Because we look at the borders and not the rectangles themselves

Here is an example of one choose:

[image: grid with 4 point that make rectangle]

We can calculate all the possible choices to chose 2 horizontal point and 2  vertical point using the binomial formula:

[image: (n+1 choose 2) * (m+1 choose 2)]

Answer (score 3):

For this lets assume you've `m` columns and `n` rows:

```
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
```

In above grid, `m` is 4 and `n` is 3. Let say you need to know how many rectangle you can form if you select top-left point. If you select top left-corner i.e.

```
* . . .
. . . .
. . . .
```

You have have `3` point to choose in right and 2 points to choose at bottom, therefore total combinations are: `3*2 = 6`.

Therefore total number rectangle you can form will correspond to total number of rectangles at each point starting from `(0, 0)` (`top left` assume to be `0, 0`) till `(m-1, n-1)`.

If you try to find summation of this:

```
[(m-1)*(n-1) + (m-2)*(n-1) + (m-3)*(n-1) ... + (n-1)] + 
[(m-1)*(n-2) + (m-2)*(n-2) ... + 1*(n-2)] +
[(m-1)*(n-3) + (m-2)*(n-3) ... + 1*(n-3)] +
...
```

Which is equal to

```
(n-1)*(1 + 2 + .. + m-1)
+
(n-2)*(1 + 2 + .. + m-1)
+
.
.
+
1*(1 + 2 + ... + m-1)
```

So you get

```
(1 + 2 + ... + n-1) * ( 1 + 2 + 3 ... + m-1)
= mn(n-1)(m-1)/4
```

Since `m` and `n` is your case are not number of point but number of line segments formed. Above formula can be transformed:

```
m = m + 1
&
n = n + 1
```

And it becomes

```
(n+1)(m+1)mn / 4
```

Comment: let's take `n=1` and `m=2`, then `[(m-1)*(n-1)(m+n)]/2=0` !!! Don't you think there is something wrong?

Comment: @Thomash If I understand it right, `n=1` means it single line so you should be making `0` rectangles.

Comment: You should read the question again: `1 x 2` grid has 3 sub-rectangles.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution,

In a m*n grid, we have m+1 lines and n+1 lines intersecting.

We use the fact, a rectangle can be formed by choosing a intersection point between these lines and another point which is not in either the horizontal or vertical line.

So, number of ways to choose a intersection point is  *(m+1)(n+1)*.
and subsequently the number of ways to choose the second point is [which is number of ways to choose a intersection point excluding the points in the same horizontal and vertical line] is *((m+1)(n+1)-n-m-1)*

Now consider a 1x1 grid , we use the fact this grid can be counted 4 times each uniquely by the 4 points.

Therefore the total number of rectangles which can formed is *[(m+1)(n+1)((m+1)(n+1)-n-m-1)]/4*

which can be simplified further to *[(m+1)(n+1)(m)(n)]/4*

Answer (score 1):

There are ((m+1)*m*n*(n+1))/4 rectangles including squares [subset of rectangles]

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer should be `(m(m+1)n(n+1))/4` minus the number of squares in the rectangular grid.

Comment: Hi Shashank. You are answering to a pretty old question that already has an accepted answer. Can you explain in your post why it is better than the other answers?